# New document opened from content type path, need to save to document library directly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have a requirement of saving the document open from a custom menu into the document library as the way it behaves when we open a document from the outofbox 'New menu' in a document library.

When we open document from the New menu, tries to save it, by default gets saved in the document library(i.e. http:// sp2010:4444/NewDocLib). When open from the custom menu and tries to save, it saves to the library’s content type path(i.e. http://eccoe-sps2010:4444/NewDocLib/Forms/III Level   here "III level" is content type name).

We have to save it to document library directly and not the content types path. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use editDocumentWithProgID2 js function in your custom menu. This function is called in standart SharePoint menu. You can see more details in [this post](http://www.informationworker.co.za/blogs/mirror/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1330).